# Is there a word to describe the Payment Options of Splitting the Total Amount of Purchase with Credit Card?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I buy something in the department store with a credit card, the clerk usually asks me, "Would you like to pay it all at once, or would you prefer to charge part of it to your account?"

Is there any conventional English language word or phrase useful for describing this manner of payment option?

Comment: Do you want a word that emphasises paying part now and the rest later? Or that emphasises paying by credit card? When you pay later with the credit card do you mean one lump sum or parts of the remainder progressively?

Comment: @Zebrafish I'd like to know what we call to split the whole payment evenly for a designated number of months like 10 months or a year like that

Comment: Hate to be difficult, but something like this gets pretty specific, like for example if you're paying off a home it's a mortgage, if automatic payments are taken from your card it might be direct debit or direct withdrawal.

Comment: There is "payment in installments", but that applies whether or not a credit card is used.  Normally, you just use your credit card at the department store to pay the whole bill, then make installment payments to the credit card issuer.

Comment: You're referring to the infrastructure inherent to different *payment systems* (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_system). *Credit* cards are distinguished by their retail or consumer base and are explicitly intended for use as *revolving* systems of personal credit, i.e., a *balance* of transactions against which interest is charged by the issuing vendor (e.g., Visa, Mastercard, Amex, your bank, etc.). *Charge* cards, on the other hand (such as Amex built its business on), do *not* revolve and are intended to be entirely paid off upon receipt of each month's statement.

Answer (score 2):

The technical term seems to be:

> **hire-purchase**
>   (Commerce)
>   a. a system for purchasing merchandise, such as cars or furniture, in which the buyer takes possession of the merchandise on payment of a deposit and completes the purchase by paying a series of regular instalments while the seller retains ownership until the final instalment is paid.
>   [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hire-purchase)

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article, Americans may be more familiar with the term **installment plan**. [Hire-purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hire_purchase)

However, I have to say these are rather technical terms. A more familiar term might be:
**payment plan**
[businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/payment-plan.html)

Comment: The credit card industry calls these *installment payments*.

Comment: typicalled called  lease/options here in the states

Comment: @lbf So many terms. I've wondered how they get by on the law Stack Exchange site for people asking advice. It's like a different rule wherever you go.

Comment: @I think the asker wants more daily terms not which is not too much technical. What usually does cashier ask in the States when people buy with credit card to check whether the buyer wants to be paid directly or wants to split the bill for several months?

Comment: @Beverlie the cashier accepts the cc and the item is paid for.  the terms and condition of how the buyer pays this debit if not her concern.  Unless the 'store issues the credit ' and this gets complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have posed 2 questions but both seem to revolve around paying by a credit card:

> 1 " ... how I could say to the seller?"

You ask the seller: "what are my payment options?"

> 2 "I'd like to know what we call to split the whole payment evenly for
>   a designated number of months like 10 months or a year like that"

**amortize**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/amortizing)

am•or•tize

v.t. -tized, -tiz•ing.
1. to liquidate (a debt), esp. by periodic payments to the creditor

As in:

> I would like to purchase that item and **amortize** the payments over 10
>   months using my credit card.

using a **credit card** can facilitate this ... with interest. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/credit-card)

> A plastic card having a magnetic strip, issued by a bank or business
>   authorizing the holder to buy goods or services on credit. Also called
>   charge card.

Comment: I love this word, kill that payment off, kill it good.

Comment: "I would like to purchase that item and amortize the payments over 10 months using my credit card." thumbs up for it